# ZFS drive is unavail after adding new drives to the computer

Tags: zfs, ubuntu-18.04

I have a server that I just recently redid, new drives, fresh OS (Ubuntu Server 18.04)

I set up a new pool with the two new drives (4 tb each) with: `zpool create poolname mirror /dev/sda /dev/sdb`

It was working fine. Then I shut down the machine, put in the two old drives (also 4tb each) and copied over the data from the old mdadm raid to the new pool. Well today I did a `zpool status` and it's degraded with a message that one of the drives is unavailable, it shows the internal ID of the drive and that it "was /dev/sdb1". Well it seems that the two old drives got loaded in as /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc, and that the second drive in my pool is now /dev/sdd.

I tried a couple variations of `zpool replace ID`, and `zpool replace ID /dev/sdd` and both times get a message that it is a part of the active pool 'poolname'. How do I fix this?

I have confirmed the drive is there with fdisk -l